# ¿Se puede aplicar un look and feel en javafx?

Tags: javafx, look-and-feel

Estoy intentando aplicar un look and feel en javafx, pero no encuentro nada por ningún lado.

Mi intención es aplicar el llamado Napkin.

Comment: Napkin es un LAF para Java Swing...

Answer (score -1):

Las apariencias de [java-swing](/questions/tagged/java-swing) no se pueden aplicar con Java Fx.

JavaFX 1.2 viene con una apariencia por defecto que se llama [Caspian](http://fxexperience.com/2009/06/caspian-skin/) y con la salida de JavaFX 8 se agrega otra apariencia llamada [Modena](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/).

Puedes hallar algunas otras si buscas en los repositorios de código libre, pero entre las principales razones de la incompatibilidad esta que JavaFX permite el uso de una versión modificada de CSS para un control mas personalizado de la apariencia de las aplicaciones